# Convert a pandas list column to individual dataframe columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

My dataframe column is as follows,

```
data['indicators'].dtype
dtype('O')

data['indicators']

0        A: 84.0% \\n B: 16.0%
1        C: 100.0%
2        C: 100.0%
3        D: 100.0%
4        A: 100.0%
5        D: 78.0% \\n A: 22.0%
6        A: 34.0% \\n B: 33.0% \\n C: 33.0%
```

I want to convert this into,

```
         A          B           C           D
0        84         16          0           0
1        0          0           100         0
2        0          0           100         0
3        0          0           0           100
4        100        0           0           0
5        22         0           0           78
6        34         33          33          0
```

I have been trying out different things like splitting using "" and ":", but the code seems to be getting too complex with multiple loops. Trying to find a better , efficient way to do this.

Any recommendations would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehesion with DataFrame constructor:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split(':') for y in x.replace(' ','').split('\\n')) 
                   for x in data['indicators'].replace('.0%','', regex=True)])
        .fillna(0).astype(int))

print (df)
     A   B    C    D
0   84  16    0    0
1    0   0  100    0
2    0   0  100    0
3    0   0    0  100
4  100   0    0    0
5   22   0    0   78
6   34  33   33    0
```

Similar solution:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split(':') 
                    for y in x.replace(' ','').replace('%','').split('\\n')) 
                    for x in data['indicators']])
        .fillna(0).astype(float).astype(int))

print (df)
     A   B    C    D
0   84  16    0    0
1    0   0  100    0
2    0   0  100    0
3    0   0    0  100
4  100   0    0    0
5   22   0    0   78
6   34  33   33    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(data['indicators']
 .str.extractall('([A-Z]):\s*(\d+.?\d*)')
 .droplevel(1)
 .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
 .fillna(0).astype(float)
)
```

Output:

```
       A     B      C      D
0   84.0  16.0      0      0
1      0     0  100.0      0
2      0     0  100.0      0
3      0     0      0  100.0
4  100.0     0      0      0
5   22.0     0      0   78.0
6   34.0  33.0   33.0      0
```

If you just want integers:

```
(data['indicators']
 .str.extractall('([A-Z]):\s*(\d+)')
 .droplevel(1)
 .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
 .fillna(0).astype(int)
)
```

Output:

```
     A   B    C    D
0   84  16    0    0
1    0   0  100    0
2    0   0  100    0
3    0   0    0  100
4  100   0    0    0
5   22   0    0   78
6   34  33   33    0
```